# RequireJS with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, requirejs

I am wondering if it is possible to use RequireJS with Google Apps Script.  I am loading RequireJS 2.1.5 from a GAS library.  This sample app should log the word Monkey but nothing happens when I test it.  No errors or warnings are being generated either.

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script data-main="main" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.5/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.gs:

```
var define = Require.loadDefine();
var require = Require.loadRequire();

define( function() {
  Logger.log("Monkey");
});
```

code.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log("doGet");
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE); 

  var t;
  t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  return t.evaluate();
}
```

Comment: You only `define` the module. You are not `require`ing the module, so the module's factory function will not have executed yet.

Comment: Have you checked that there are no errors in the web app (F12 in Chrome and IE)? I have a feeling that your html doesn't know where to find "main" after the [Cajoling of Caja](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) has been completed by the HTML Service output.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer while reading [JavaScript Module Pattern: In-Depth](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

The code inside the module didn't have access to Logger.  Passing this as a parameter makes it work.

```
define( function(g) {
  g.Logger.log("Monkey");
}(this));
```